# Cold water faucet valve not shutting off the water in bathtub

Tags: plumbing

The cold water side of my bathtub faucet will not shut the water off completely. I have removed the valve stem, carried it to a plumbing supply store and he put a new gasket

Comment: Are you saying that it still leaks, after gasket replacement? Can you post some photos on Imgur and we will add them to your question?

Comment: Sometimes a chunk of the old washer or other debris get stuck in the seat. You may have to pull the stem and clear any debris out, in rare cases the seat is damaged but your plumbing store should have a seat dressing tool that can clean up minor imperfections in the seat.

Comment: No it is not just leaking, I am saying it will NOT turn the water off and the water coming out of my tub spout is cold water not hot, so everything I have done, I did on cold water side. While stem was out, after using the reseating tool, I cleaned it out before re installing the stem